# Python set a list but keep indexes of original list

Tags: python, list, indexing, set

I am trying to set a list but i want to keep the indexes of the remaining list as in before.

```
list_a = ['cat','dog','cat','mouse','dog']

list_b = [ 'c','c','c','d','d']
```

`zipped = zip(list_a,list_b)`

I want to `set` on list_a but i also want to remove the corresponding values of list_b that is removed from list_a after the set.

example of what i want:

```
new_zip 
>>> [('cat','c'),('dog','c'),('mouse','d')]
```

i thought zipping the 2 list could give me what i want but i might not be able to set the zipped list because of the second argument of the tuples.

Comment: What determines whether you keep "c" or "d" for "dog"?

Comment: `list_b` should exactly map to `list_a`

Comment: You have two instances of "dog", mapping to "c" and "d".  When you reduce list_a to a set, how do you decide which index to keep?

Comment: best if it was a zipped list, and set only on the first argument of the tuples and delete entire tuple if there is duplicate of the first argument of the tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Python version, you can do the following:

Python 2:

```
dict(zip(list_a, list_b)).items()
```

Python 3:

```
list(dict(zip(list_a, list_b)).items())
```

Both return a list of tuples, equivalent to the output that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't mind using an external library you could use [`iteration_utilities.unique_everseen`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/unique_everseen.html). It's like a `set` but allows to use a `key`-function and keeps the first encountered value:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import unique_everseen
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(unique_everseen(zip(list_a, list_b), key=itemgetter(0)))
[('cat', 'c'), ('dog', 'c'), ('mouse', 'd')]
```

---

Disclaimer: The [`iteration_utilities` package](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities) was written by me. But you can find an almost equivalent recipe in the [`itertools` Recipes documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score -1):

Try a dictionary comprehension?

```
list_a = ['cat','dog','cat','mouse','dog']
list_b = [ 'c','c','c','d','d']
my_dict = {list_a[i] : list_b[i] for i in range(len(list_a))}
print (my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'cat': 'c', 'dog': 'd', 'mouse': 'd'}
```

Now you can extract the keys and values as you wish.  Does that get you close enough to a solution?

Comment: mydict = dict(zip(list_a,list_b)), should also result in the same result.